# Find substring that is closest to position needed

Tags: php, string, substring

I have big string with occurrence needed. And I need to find closest substring to this occurrence.

For example:

```
<p>one</p><p>two</p><p>three and some more</p><p>four</p><p>five</p>
```

I am looking for "three", I know it position and I need to get only `<p>` block with this occurrence.

```
<p>three and some more</p>
```

Can I find closest `<p>` with known position without regexp using?

Comment: Just curious, why do you need to do that in PHP exactly, since this seems like HTML manipulation stuff?

Comment: @NorthBridge Search results output for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use strpos with a starting index to search after, strrpos to search before.

Edited: strrpos finds the last occurence, so you need to cut the string before.

```
$s = "<p>one</p><p>two</p><p>three and some more</p><p>four</p><p>five</p>";
$position = strpos($s, "three");
$end_p = strpos($s, "</p>", $position);
$previous_p = strrpos(substr($s, 0, $position), "<p>");

var_dump(substr($s, $previous_p, $end_p - $previous_p + 4));
```

Comment: `var_dump(substr($s, $next_p, $previous_p));` outputs `'<p>four</p><p>five</'`

Comment: Yes but the second argument of substr is the length, not the end position... Add +3 to print the ending <p>. Though that's basic string processing, the really important thing is to know strrpos finds the last one...
var_dump(substr($s, $previous_p, $next_p - $previous_p + 3)));

Comment: I need only `<p>three and some more</p>`

Comment: Yeah, it seems what i needed. But I will change "+4" with "+strlen(</p>)"

Answer (score 2):

I think you can [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.convert-cyr-string.php) your string as an array and the get the known substring position from the array

```
$string = '<p>one</p><p>two</p><p>three and some more</p><p>four</p><p>five</p>';
$str_array = explode("</p>",$string);
$sub_str = $str_array[2].'</p>';
echo $sub_str;
//output <p>three and some more</p>
```

[**Live sample**](http://codepad.org/X7UWu5uB)

If i stead you need to find the occurence of the word `three`

```
$string = '<p>one</p><p>two</p><p>three and some more</p><p>four</p><p>five</p>';
$str_array = explode("</p>",$string);
foreach($str_array as $value)
{
    if(strpos($value,'three'))
    {
        $sub_str = $value.'</p>';
    }
}

echo $sub_str;
//output <p>three and some more</p>
```

[**Live sample**](http://codepad.org/M7jcOZeQ)

Comment: But you knew "2" index is you needed. I have only "three" position in source string.

Comment: This is 2 because array count starts from 0 so 3rd position is actually equal to 2

Comment: On other hands i can have missunderstood your question, are you looking for number three in letters?

Comment: Sorry. It's hard (English is not my language) but I try to explain. You tell me I need foreach str_array for looking index needed.

Comment: Yeah, I told about it. I don't want to check array. But thank you very much for your solution